# Best way to divvy up screen space in pictorial article mobile app?

Tags: iphone, scrolling, touch-screen, text, image

I'm working on an iPhone app that gives users access to image-heavy articles. We want to showcase the images--they're like the bread and butter of the app, so we're opting for a kind of scrolling thumbnail gallery within each story.

So my question is, what is the best way to handle this? Specifically:

1. Is it always preferable to show the text of an article? Would you ever want to make it appear only by a button, swipe, or other user action?
2. Where is the best place to put the article's image thumbnail gallery?

We're kind of arguing about it here at work and I'd like as many 3rd party views as are out there! Let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making Image Heavy Article browser, the name itself tells you what is the right thing to do. By article, we mean Text and readable content which may further have images, videos etc - but if you take article out, its simile image gallery about a subject.

Your objectives of making this app might advocate heavily to give prominence to images and there is no harm in doing that but let images be seen belonging to articles.

Something like that may help.

[image]

Comment: I like this concept of showing the images in a kind of masonry layout...I hadn't thought of that, and it's one to consider. I suppose you would have the images pop up, or open on a new screen when you tapped on them. As you mentioned about prominence, I think I prefer the images to be on the top half of the screen rather than the bottom, however. What is your feeling about keeping the title on top, followed by the images, followed by the text?

Comment: We may have different understanding about your product defination but the way I understood, it is an app which lets you browse image heavy articles. If this is the case, I would want content to be seen as article with images - even though images are more accessible than standard article. With this definition in view, text, the article itself comes first. You can choose to show only 3,4 lines of text and remaining text can be loaded on demand. REGARDING DISPLAYING IMAGES, yes they can be opened in overlay window with option to go forward, back and close(back) to article + images view.